# How do I export multiple 'sub-modules' from one node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Here's what I mean by exporting 'sub-modules':

```
var fibers = require('fibers');         // this works, it's the 'main' module
var future = require('fibers/future');  // this also works, it's a 'sub'-module
```

How would I do this 'abc/xyz' export? I've gone through the `fibers` source code a little bit, and it doesn't seem like this is something that node/npm will do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents an actual filesystem path. So, in the root directory of your *abc* module, call a file `xyz.js` or `xyz.json`, or create an `xyz/` directory with an `index.js`.